is there a way to find the bitrate of the video and audio in youtube stats for nerds?
i know how to read the codecs as opus and mp4a (aac) and vp9 and other stuff like that but I don't know how to find the bitrate for the video and the audio.
I saw the numbers beside the codec things but they were just itag numbers and I don't know what that is.
